# On resize less than 1200px only carousel. otherwise, "unslick"

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Used below Slick JS for our component. Its works fine only when user resize from desktop to mobile (less than 767px) and refresh the page manually.

How to make this script work during resize itself? Less than 1200px only need to initialise the slick. more than that no slick, only div column container.

```
$('.listing.columns').slick({                    
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,       
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
            variableWidth: true,
            responsive: [
            {
                breakpoint: 9999,
                settings: 'unslick'
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 1200,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 3,
                    slidesToScroll: 3,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true
                }
            },{
                breakpoint: 767,
                settings: {
                    slidesToShow: 1,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    infinite: true,
                    dots: true,
                    prevArrow: false
                }
            }]
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including a `window` resize event to see if you can watch it like this:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $('.listing.columns').slick('resize');
});
```

Also `prevArrow` does not accept a boolean as a value,
it needs to be of the following type:
`string (html|jQuery selector) | object (DOM node|jQuery object)`

```js
$('.listing.columns').slick({                    
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,       
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    variableWidth: true,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 9999,
        settings: 'unslick'
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1200,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
          variableWidth: true
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          variableWidth: false,
        }
      } 
    ]
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $('.listing.columns').slick('resize');
});
```

```css
.listing-el {
  line-height: 100px;
  background-color: #00DBDE;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
}

.listing-el-small {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #4158D0;
}

.listing-el-large {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #FBDA61;
}

.listing-el-xlarge {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #21D4FD;
}

@media(min-width:1201px){
  .listing-el {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css" integrity="sha512-yHknP1/AwR+yx26cB1y0cjvQUMvEa2PFzt1c9LlS4pRQ5NOTZFWbhBig+X9G9eYW/8m0/4OXNx8pxJ6z57x0dw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" integrity="sha512-6lLUdeQ5uheMFbWm3CP271l14RsX1xtx+J5x2yeIDkkiBpeVTNhTqijME7GgRKKi6hCqovwCoBTlRBEC20M8Mg==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="listing columns">
  <div class="listing-el listing-el-large">1</div>
  <div class="listing-el listing-el-small">2</div>
  <div class="listing-el listing-el-xlarge">3</div>
  <div class="listing-el">4</div>
  <div class="listing-el listing-el-xlarge">5</div>
  <div class="listing-el">6</div>
  <div class="listing-el">7</div>
  <div class="listing-el listing-el-small">8</div>
  <div class="listing-el">9</div>
  <div class="listing-el listing-el-large">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After putting this code, when resize from desktop to mobile.. carousel got hidden (i think not initializing).

Comment: @WTE Updated with a running example above, seems to be working fine. Make sure to set width to your items since you use ```variableWidth``` and change the ```prevArrow``` value. If you want to scroll only 1 item on small screen, you should switch off ```variableWidth```, as shown for small devices.